# How do I set the deafult date within ASPxDateEdit only after the calendar has been expanded

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

My page has a DateEdit control than must be blank when the page initially displays.  When the user expands to view the calendar, I want to set the default date to be something other than Today.  But only within the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to implement the postponed date selection via the client-side functionality:

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ...>
    <ClientSideEvents DropDown="function(s, e) {
        if (!s.GetDate())
            s.SetDate(new Date());
    }" />
</dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  If the Date property is set, the date text will be displayed.  And there doesn't seem to be an event which triggers before the calendar opens where you could set the Date property manually.

Comment: Ha!  I like it.  Let me try it out.